# VueJS, Axios, Laravel - catch errors

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am using the following code to post something to Laravel:

```
        upload: async function() {     

        response = await axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.response.data.errors);
        });
```

(Unrelated code omited)

This works overall when Laravel returns 200.
If I return 401, 422 or something from Laravel Axios throws an error in the console and the whole method stops running.

I've always considered this a very non-developer-friendly behavior - am I not understanding it? Returning different status codes from your backend API is supposed to help reading the response in Vue, but Vue/Axios treat every non-200 response as a fatal error.

How can I catch the error - do something (and bind `$this` to the callback) and then continue with the method without killing the whole script?

Comment: If you read the [accepted HTTP codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), `axios` is doing what is should do. Do you think a redirect (`3xx`) is a successful response from an API ? How about `4xx/5xx` ? If your code stops working when you get a `4xx`, that's because you are doing something wrong, you are using `async/await` in a bad way, you have to use `try/catch` and not `await + js.catch`... That is why your code stops working...

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that Axios default has a validator function like this:

```js
 validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300; // default
 },
```

Status codes 300 and above and less than 200 will make axios throw.

You can make it not throw (stop the further execution) by either:

try..catch:

```js
try {
    response = await axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    this.doSomething() // this is available here
}
```

.catch on axios:

```js
axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data.errors);
});
```

NOTE: This is different to your example due to not using async/await

Error callback:

```js
axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
}, error => {
    console.log(error.response.data.errors);
})
```

If you do not want Axios to force you that status codes above 300 will throw, you can make change the default axios validator:

```js
axios.defaults.validateStatus = (status) => {
    return status === 200; // your own logic here to throw or not.
};
```

Comment: Best answer, but I recommend (to the question's author) to not change the default Axios' behavior. It will confuse anyone else that is used to this default...